# Flutter LisView.builder scroll to bottom

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm building an app that handles `messaging` between users and I ran into a problem when a user sends a new **message** and the **system keyboard** is open the new message is hidden by it,

I need my `ListView.builder` to when a new message is sent scroll down to show the last message,
So far and tried using the `scrollController` like this

```js
  _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
```

but is not doing anything.

So am looking for a way to resolve this problem this is my code

```js
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: userChat.value.messages!.length,
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  /*
                * DateChip(
                    date: new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 2),
                  ),
                * */
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      BubbleNormal(
                        text: '${userChat.value.messages![index].message}',
                        isSender: userChat.value.messages![index].messageId ==
                            currentUser.uidToken,
                        color: Constants.themeColor2,
                        bubbleRadius: 20.0,
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                      ),
                      BubbleNormal(
                        text: DateFormat('hh:mm a')
                            .format(userChat.value.messages![index].dateTime),
                        isSender: userChat.value.messages![index].messageId ==
                            currentUser.uidToken,
                        color: Constants.themeColor2,
                        bubbleRadius: 20.0,
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
});
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but now when i try the scroll to bottom i get this error **ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 107 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'**

Comment: in the end use this solution inside the return of the build of my widget since I update the listview every time a new message arrives thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Timer(
  Duration.zero,
  () => {
    _scrollController
      .jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
  },
);
```